# overriding Backbone.View delegateEvents so the events object can include mobile events

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, hammer.js

I am using Hammer.js to capture touchscreen events in a Backbone View. Hammer has a special syntax for adding touch listeners, which I have been using in the View's initialize function:

```
$("#next-button").hammer({prevent_default: true}).on('tap', $.proxy(this.next, this));
```

I would rather add it to the standard events object, like this:

```
events: {"tap #next-button":"next"}
```

So I hacked the end of Backbone.View's delegateEvents method:

```
var isMobileEvent=["tap", "doubleTap"].indexOf(eventName)!=-1;
        if (selector === '') {
            if (isMobileEvent){
                this.$el.hammer({prevent_default: true}).on(eventName, method);
            } else {
                this.$el.on(eventName, method);
            }
        } else {
            if (isMobileEvent){
                this.$el.hammer({prevent_default: true}).on(eventName, selector, method);
            } else {
                this.$el.on(eventName, selector, method);
            }

        }
```

This works fine. But when I tried to override the method in the one View where it was needed  the override (worried that I would forget about this hack in Backbone, or overwrite it with a new version of Backbone, etc.), delegateEvents for my View stopped working. The problem is that the method callback is not recognized as a method:

```
if (!_.isFunction(method)) method = this[events[key]];
```

Why? I literally copy and pasted the function into the View subclass. Here is the whole delegateEvents that works in Backbone, but not in my Backbone.View:

```
delegateEvents: function(events) {
      if (!(events || (events = _.result(this, 'events')))) return;
      this.undelegateEvents();
      for (var key in events) {
        var method = events[key];
        if (!_.isFunction(method)) method = this[events[key]];
        if (!method) throw new Error('Method "' + events[key] + '" does not exist');
        var match = key.match(delegateEventSplitter);
        var eventName = match[1], selector = match[2];
        method = _.bind(method, this);
        eventName += '.delegateEvents' + this.cid;
        var isMobileEvent=["tap", "doubleTap"].indexOf(eventName)!=-1;
        if (selector === '') {
            if (isMobileEvent){
                this.$el.hammer({prevent_default: true}).on(eventName, method);
            } else {
                this.$el.on(eventName, method);
            }
        } else {
            if (isMobileEvent){
                this.$el.hammer({prevent_default: true}).on(eventName, selector, method);
            } else {
                this.$el.on(eventName, selector, method);
            }

        }
      }
```

THE FIX:

Replace this line:

```
var match = key.match(delegateEventSplitter);
```

with this one:

```
var match = key.match(/^(\S+)\s*(.*)$/);
```

Comment: How did you override it?

Comment: Do you have a `next` function/method in your `View` class?

Comment: @Loamhoof I simply added a delegateEvents method to the View subclass. I've never overridden a js function or a Backbone one, either. Would this be sufficient? Code in other StackOverflow posts seemed to follow this pattern.

Comment: @MattGarland - could you set a breakpoint in your class and see what the scope is at the time that it's throwing the error? Something odd is happening that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @WiredPrairie: "this" is the view subclass instance. "closure scope", weirdly, just has "toString" in it. I am looking in the watch panel in Firefox.

Comment: Where are you declaring `delegateEventSplitter`? I copied the `delegateEvents` code into a subclass View here and it worked, after I copied the value of that variable. http://jsbin.com/iqibur/1/edit

Comment: (As you're not in the same scope as the declaration of the delegateEvents method, you don't have access to the same variables, so if you'd have to replace delegateEventSplitter by it's actual value, or define the var)

Comment: @WiredPrairie though it wouldn't make sense that the problem lies here while he said that the problematic piece of code is above :o What is exactly the error returned? (if there's one)

Comment: @WiredPrairie--yes that fixes a further problem I would have had.

Comment: @Loamhoof -- I understand that, but I wanted to show that everything can work (in a subclass), with the exception of needing the value of that regex variable.

Comment: @Loamhoof--the problem is, _.isFunction(method) returns false when it should return true. _.isFunction(this[method]) returns true, and--with WiredPrairie's fix--the listeners are added successfully, but then I have another scoping problem on the callback:  handleObj.handler.apply is not a function. I am honing in on this, at least.

Comment: @MattGarland this line is supposed to return false the way you do it. It should return true if you declared your callback in the events object. `method = this[events[key]];` is your real method. So it's normal that `this[method]` returns true. `handleObj.handler.apply is not a function` appears when you try to execute the callback?

Comment: @Loamhoof, got it, I didn't realize you could pass a function in the events object.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why I can't access this.delegateEventSplitter? I assumed it belonged to Backbone.View so it would resolve in the subclass via the prototype. But I looked at Backbone.View and found that the property was in Backbone itself, not Backbone.View. So the scope of Backbone.View is Backbone (because it is a nested function) but a subclass of Backbone.View does not have access to that scope? Backbone.View access it by closure, but MyView has no access to its prototype's closures? JS is confusing me.

Comment: @WiredPrairie--do an answer and I'll give you credit.

Comment: "*JS is confusing me.*" => that's why I love it ;) So first, if delegateEventSplitter was declared inside Backbone.View as `var delegateEventSplitter = /^(\S+)\s*(.*)$/;` it wouldn't change anything, that'd be a private var, and only the constructor and the methods declared within the constructor (not the prototype ones) would have access to it, scope problem. Now about scopes, basically you'll never have access to Backbone's scope as you need to define things within a scope to have access to it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/iqibur/1/edit) shows how it is possible to override the default Backbone `View` logic for `delegateEvents`.

You can easily extend it as needed to handle Hammer.JS as you had above to extend Backbone to support the various touch events.

I needed to copy the value of `delegateEventSplitter` locally as it's privately declared (within a closure) inside of the Backbone library. Only functions that were executed/returned within the context of that variable are able to access that value. Since your new class does not execute in that context, it's unable to directly access the value.

The relevant code:

```
var SampleView = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    "click" : '_clicked' 
  },

delegateEvents: function(events) {
      if (!(events || (events = _.result(this, 'events')))) return;
      this.undelegateEvents();
      for (var key in events) {
        var method = events[key];
        if (!_.isFunction(method)) method = this[events[key]];
        if (!method) throw new Error('Method "' + events[key] + '" does not exist');
        var match = key.match(/^(\S+)\s*(.*)$/);
        var eventName = match[1], selector = match[2];
        method = _.bind(method, this);
        eventName += '.delegateEvents' + this.cid;
        if (selector === '') {
           this.$el.on(eventName, method);
        } else {
           this.$el.on(eventName, selector, method);
        }
      }  
},

  render: function() {        
     this.$el.html("hi");
     return this; 
  },        
  _clicked: function() {
     alert("clicked!"); 
  }
});

// assumes there's an element with an id of "content"
$(function() {
  var view = new SampleView();
  $("#content").append(view.render().$el);  
});
```